# Parametric contour plot?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a contour of a function `g[x,y]` (in particular, the contour `g[x,y]==1`) on a different set of axes than `(x,y)`: I want to plot it on `(f1[x], f2[y])`, where `f1` and `f2` are (monotone increasing) functions of a single variable, `g[x,y]` is monotone increasing in `x` and monotone decreasing in `y`, and all 3 functions are complicated enough that I cannot invert them (analytically, and probably not numerically either).  I managed to plot `g=1` vs. `(x,y)` but can't figure out how to plot it against `(f1[x], f2[y])` without setting up huge tables of data and then just plotting points.  I can only conceive of it along the lines of

```
ParametricContourPlot[g[x, y] == 1, {f1[x], f2[y]}, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

but of course that doesn't exist (AFAIK).  Any ideas?

EDIT: My thanks to Bill and Rahul for their quick answers, and my apologies for any ambiguity in my original post. Rahul correctly interpreted what I needed--my sincere (and awed) thanks!  My `f1`, `f2` and `g` functions are so complicated I can't even write them in closed form, but Rahul's suggestion worked perfectly. (I still don't understand how `MeshFunctions` works to map the function onto the new axes, but it clearly does.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's call $u=f_1(x)$ and $v=f_2(y)$. Do you want to plot $g(u,v)=1$ against $x$ and $y$, or $g(x,y)=1$ against $u$ and $v$? @bill's answer does the former. Here's a way to do the latter: Use `ParametricPlot`, and define the contour using `MeshFunctions`.

```
f1[x_] := Log[1 + x]
f2[y_] := Exp[y] - 1
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

ParametricPlot[{f1[x], f2[y]}, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{u, v, x, y}, g[x, y]]}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Black]]
```

[image]

You can set `PlotStyle -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, Axes -> False` if you want it to look more similar to the default `ContourPlot`.

Unfortunately, it seems that `MaxRecursion` doesn't help to improve the contour, so if you need better quality you'll have to increase `PlotPoints`.

Answer (score 8):

It's simpler than you fear. First the command is ContourPlot... for a simple `g`, this will give you the circle of radius 1.

```
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
ContourPlot[g[x, y] == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

Now say you have the two functions `f1` and `f2`

```
f1[x_] := Log[x];
f2[y_] := Exp[y];
ContourPlot[g[f1[x], f2[y]] == 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you get the contour plot of the nested functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can also post-process the output of `ContourPlot` to transform the contour lines using a transformation that depends on two functions `t1` and `t1`:

```
postProcess[t1_, t2_, col_: LightBlue] := Show[# /. GraphicsComplex[c_, p_] :> 
   GraphicsComplex[Transpose[{t1 /@ #, t2 /@ #2} & @@ Transpose[c]], p], 
    PlotRange -> All] /. Line[x_] :> {Thick, Line[x], col, Polygon[x]} &
```

Using the example in @Rahul's answer with a slight modification:

```
f1[x_] := Re @ Log[1 + x]
f2[y_] := Re[Exp[y] - 1]
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2

cp = ContourPlot[g[x, y] == 1, {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{Style["y", 16], ""}, {Style["x", 16], ""}},  ImageSize -> 400];

Row[{cp, Show[postProcess[f1, f2] @ cp,  FrameLabel -> 
  {{Style[Subscript[f, 2][y], 16], ""}, {Style[Subscript[f, 1][x], 16], ""}}]}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
cp2 = ContourPlot[g[x, y], {x, -1.2, 1.2}, {y, -1.2, 1.2}, 
  Contours -> {.1, .5, 1}, FrameLabel -> {{Style["y", 16], ""}, {Style["x", 16], ""}}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, ContourShading -> None];

Row[{cp2, Show[postProcess[f1, f2] @ cp2,  FrameLabel -> 
  {{Style[Subscript[f, 2][y], 16], ""}, {Style[Subscript[f, 1][x], 16], ""}}]}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]