# multiple or variable x scales in [list]plot

Tags: plotting

I need to make a plot (in this case a ListPlot) in which the x (horizontal) scale varies: either piecewise linear or a single nonconstant function. The purpose is to plot data for graphs like this one:

[image: gr]

(never mind that the graph shows multiple curves), which shows the advance of HIV within a patient on multiple timescales (first the acute stage, then the longer chronic stage). But I can't figure out how to rescale the x-axis (I saw a post on this site involving a ListDatePlot scatterplot but couldn't make sense of the code); I suspect it requires some sort of virtuoso use of exotic plot options and rescaling functions.

For grins here is a list which follows one of the graphs in the HIV plot, with the x coordinate in years; I'd want either a linear scale from 0 to 1/4 and then a different linear scale from 1/4 to 11, or a scaling function which expands [0,1/4] relative to [1/4,11], like (1 - Exp[-10 x]) (0.7 x + 3).

```
CD4list = {{1/52, 1020}, {3/52, 900}, {6/52, 500}, {9/52, 600}, {12/52, 660},
 {1, 600}, {2, 575}, {3, 500}, {4, 400}, {5, 400}, {6, 350}, {7, 280},
 {8, 220}, {9, 60}, {10, 30}, {11, 20}};
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [(8241)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8241/121).  That one deals with the *y* axis but at first glance I believe the methods given can be applied here.

Comment: This may be true; unfortunately I can't even read (parse) the code there to understand whether the undesired y-interval is being rescaled or removed altogether--the emphasis in that question is to suppress an interval but show y-ranges on either side of the suppressed interval at the same scale. Here I don't want to suppress any interval, just stretch one part of the domain relative to the rest (different scales). If those methods can be used here, I'm afraid I need a little more hand-holding to get there.

Comment: I agree.  If I understand you may be able to accomplish this by creating multiple plots and (hopefully seamlessly) joining them together, therefore also see: [(6877)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6877/121).  (You would want to turn off the `Frame` on the joined edges.)  If I have time later I may attempt an implementation.

Comment: I agree two joined plots should work. Unfortunately the code in #6877 uses no commands I know. I don't even know what @ means here. Another possibility might be the approach used in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66354/parametric-contour-plot to transform the axes (in this case just the x-axis).

Comment: FYI to all, I finally achieved what I was looking for, in a manual, kludgy, non-generalizable way, by defining a transform function (in this case, f[x_] = Min[40 x/3, 80 (x - 1/4)/129 + 10/3], piecewise linear with slope change at x=1/4), using it to transform the list's x coordinates, ListPlotting the transformed list, and using FrameTicks to specify tick labels which are the inverse transforms of the apparent labels (e.g., I told it to place a tick at f[1] and label it 1).  I also used FrameTicks to place a dotted vertical line at f[1/4] (labeled 1/4) to mark where the scale changes.

Comment: Nice method.  It would be appropriate to post that as a self-answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is likely more or less what @Christopher describes in his comment. Note by using `Interpolation` and `ParametricPlot` we ensure the curve is continuous (and correct) across the transition breaks (otherwise you would need to ensure you had a data point at the breaks )

```
 CD4listf = Interpolation[CD4list, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
 breaks = {1/4, 3, Infinity};
 slopes = {1, 1/10, 1/50};
 xmap[x_] = 
    Piecewise[
       Fold[ Append[ # , {(#[[-1, 1]] /. 
           x ->  #[[-1, 2, 2]]) + #2[[2]] (x - #[[-1, 2, 2]]) , 
            x < #2[[1]] }] & ,
            {{x slopes[[1]], x < breaks[[1]]}} , 
               Transpose[{breaks[[2 ;;]], slopes[[2 ;;]]}]]];
 SetAttributes[xmap, Listable]
 ds = 0.005; dy = 30;(*axis cut parameters*)
 ParametricPlot[Through[{xmap, CD4listf}[x]], {x, 1/52, 11},
     AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio ,
     Ticks -> {Through[{xmap, # &}[#]] & /@ {.05, .1, .15, .2, .5, 1, 1.5,
                                               2, 2.5, 5, 8, 11}, Automatic} ,
     PlotRangeClipping -> False,
     PlotPoints -> 1000,
     PlotRange -> {xmap[{0, 11}], Automatic},
     Epilog -> ({
         Line[{{# - ds, -dy}, {# + ds, dy}}] & /@ xmap[breaks[[;; -2]]] ,
         Point[{xmap[#[[1]]], #[[2]]} & /@ CD4list]})]
```

[image]

here is the scale mapping for reference:

```
     Plot[xmap[x], {x, 0, 11}]
```

[image]