# How to make Piecewise continuous

Tags: functions, piecewise

I have a function defined by its slope in a continuous sequence of intervals, e.g.

```
intervals = {{0, 10}, {10, 15}, {15, 25}}
slopes = {4, 5, 6}
fun = Piecewise@MapThread[{#2*(b - #1[[1]]), #1[[1]] < b <= #1[[2]]} &, {intervals,slopes}]
Plot[fun, {b, Min@Flatten@intervals, Max@Flatten@intervals}]
```

[image: piecewise]

I would like this function to be continuous. What I thought is to accumulate the constants one interval at a time and then go through and add them back to the function, which works fine but is in principle O(N) in the number of intervals:

```
constants = Prepend[Accumulate[fun /. ({b -> #} & /@ (intervals\[Transpose][[2]]))][[;; -2]], 0]
funWithConstants = Piecewise@MapThread[{#1[[1]] + #2, #1[[2]]} &, {fun[[1]], constants}]
Plot[funWithConstants, {b, Min@Flatten@intervals,Max@Flatten@intervals}]
```

[image]

Then I noticed in the documentation for Piecewise that there seems to be a native way to compute the necessary constants for the *integral* of the function:

```
Integrate[fun, b]
Plot[%, {b, Min@Flatten@intervals, Max@Flatten@intervals}]
```

[image: piecewiseintegrated]

Is there a way to use this native algorithm find such constants for the function itself? I would guess it is probably faster then mine, and maybe faster than O(N).

Comment: Look at this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71426/function-for-a-series-of-joined-slopes

Comment: nine, I propose closing this as a duplicate of the question linked above. (Incidentally my own.)  If you feel this is *not* a duplicate please edit your question to clearly explain why.

Comment: I agree with you. Could you add some tags related to Piecewise to your question? My preliminary search didn't turn it up, nor was it suggested in the sidebar.

Comment: @ninemileskid Your question will remain for others to find and serve as a  redirect to the earlier question.  That is a primary purpose of marking questions as duplicates.