# How do I convert a list to a Graph with directed edges?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I created a discrete Markov process using `p = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0,  0}, {{0, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 0}}];` and simulated it 5 times to create a list of lists:

```
data = Table[RandomFunction[p, {0, 10}][[2]][[1]][[1]], {i, 1, 5, 1}]
(*{{1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 
  3}, {1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 
  1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1}}*)
```

I would like to convert each of these lists into a list of vertices that are directed from the first member of the list to the next and then the next:

```
1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}
```

How do I do that?  I explored EdgeAdd but that doesn't give me the desired result:

```
Table[EdgeAdd[
  Graph[{data[[1]][[1]] \[DirectedEdge] data[[1]][[2]]}, 
   VertexLabels -> "Name"], 
  data[[1]][[i]] \[DirectedEdge] data[[1]][[i + 1]]],
 {i, 2, 5, 1}]
```

[image]

What function may I use to convert a list to a set of directed vertices for a Graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a list of vertices representing such a path, you can use

```
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]]
```

If you just want the graph fort his Markov process, use `Graph[p]`.

Comment: Beat you to the punch. ;^))

Comment: Oh my... this was simpler than expected.  Silly me.  Two answers at nearly the same time instance!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard 5 full seconds! :D I'll leave this though because of the `Graph[p]` bit, which I think many people don't know. (And +1)

Answer (score 6):

```
data =
  {{1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2, 
    1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2}, {1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 
    3, 2, 1, 2, 1}};

DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ data
```

> ```
> {{1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
>   1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
>   3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
>   1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
>   1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
>   2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
>   3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
>   3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
>   2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
>   2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
>   3 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
>   2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 
>   1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
>   3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3}, {1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
>   2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
>   3 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 3 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 
>   2 \[DirectedEdge] 1, 1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 1}}
> ```

Comment: Oh my... this was simpler than expected.  Silly me.

Comment: @dearN  I think we all have those days; at least I do. :-) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71445/121

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [`BlockMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockMap.html)

```
toEdges1 = BlockMap[Apply @ DirectedEdge, #, 2, 1] &;
```

or the (undocumented) 6-argument form of `Partition`:

```
toEdges2 = Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, DirectedEdge] &;
```

Using it with `data`:

```
toEdges1 /@ data
```

[image]

```
Row[Graph[#, ImageSize -> 200] & /@ toEdges1 /@ data]
```

[image]

```
toEdges1 /@ data == 
    toEdges2 /@ data == 
     ( DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ data)
```

> ```
>  True
> ```